# Getting CoreMongooseArray instead of normal array

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have this schema:

```
var orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  history: [{
    "type": {
      type: String,
      enum: [
        'ORDER_HISTORY_DRIVER_DETAILS',
        'ORDER_HISTORY_LOADING',
        'ORDER_HISTORY_LOCATION',
        'ORDER_HISTORY_UNLOADING'
      ],
      required: true
    },
    date: {
      type: Date
    },
    state: {
      type: String,
      enum: [
        'ORDER_HISTORY_STEP_STATE_COMPLETED',
        'ORDER_HISTORY_STEP_STATE_CURRENT',
        'ORDER_HISTORY_STEP_STATE_FUTURE',
      ],
      default: 'ORDER_HISTORY_STEP_STATE_FUTURE',
      required: true
    }
  }]
})
```

At one point, I need to remove all subdocuments that have a type of "ORDER_HISTORY_LOCATION", so I'm running this:

```
let result = await Order.findOneAndUpdate(
  {orderId: req.params.orderId},
  {
    $pull: {
      history: {type: "ORDER_HISTORY_LOCATION"}
    }
  }, {new: true}
);
```

When i log "result.history" i get this:

```
CoreMongooseArray [
{ state: 'ORDER_HISTORY_STEP_STATE_CURRENT',
  _id: 5caf8a41641e6717d835483d,
  type: 'ORDER_HISTORY_DRIVER_DETAILS' },
{ state: 'ORDER_HISTORY_STEP_STATE_FUTURE',
  _id: 5caf8a41641e6717d835483c,
  type: 'ORDER_HISTORY_LOADING',
  date: 2019-05-08T09:00:00.000Z },
{ state: 'ORDER_HISTORY_STEP_STATE_FUTURE',
  _id: 5caf8a41641e6717d835483b,
  type: 'ORDER_HISTORY_LOADING',
  date: 2019-05-09T09:00:00.000Z },
{ state: 'ORDER_HISTORY_STEP_STATE_FUTURE',
  _id: 5caf8a41641e6717d8354837,
  type: 'ORDER_HISTORY_UNLOADING',
  date: 2019-05-13T09:00:00.000Z } ]
```

What is this "CoreMongooseArray"? I can't do anything with it. I also can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: This is also driving me nuts, I'm trying to upgrade to Mongoose 5 and a lot of our tests are failing that were doing equality checks with plain arrays

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`CoreMongooseArray` seems to be inheriting the `Array` type and has almost the same behavior.

Source code (at the time of writting) : https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/3e523631daa48a910b5335c747b3e5d080966e6d/lib/types/core_array.js

In case you want to convert it to a simple array, just do this :

```
const history = Array.from(...result.history)
```

Beware, if this array contains objects, each object will have undesirable additional Mongoose properties, as they are Mongoose schemas documents. You will need to convert them into plain JavaScript objects :

```
const history = Array.from(...result.history).map(v => v.toJSON())
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I marked this as the answer since it gives a good explanation. It turned out that I had a typo and my code continued working after I corrected it. It was awkward because the error i was getting didn't seem to be related to the typo and that's why it was hard to find what was wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me!

```
const history = Array.from([...result.history])
```